# What is the point of string interpolation?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

At first glance, it appears to do nothing more than save 2 characters per embedded expression:

```
Console.WriteLine($"This is time number {i} that I, {name}, printed this statement.");
Console.WriteLine("This is time number "+i+" that I, "+name+", printed this statement.");
```

Is this really worth a whole language feature?

This being said, I have to admit, I do like looking at the curly braces more, so I have been using string interpolation. But why do I like it more? What psychological phenomenon prefers `{hello}` to `"+hello+"` ? Seems a bit arbitrary.

Are there other benefits to string interpolation that warrant a whole language feature? Or is it really just about the readability?

## When is string interpolation not equivalent to a simple text replacement of `"+` => `{` and `+"` => `}`?

I am aware that it gets compiled to `string.Format`. So the resulting binary is different, but the execution seems to be the same, give or take some extremely minor performance differences.

Comment: What is the difference between `"The number " + number.ToString() + " is greater than 0"` vs `string.Format(Then number {0} is greater than 0", number)`?

Comment: As for `string.Format("{0} - {1}", a, b)` vs `$"{a} - {b}"`, it's just more readable / less at risk from human error when modifying.

Comment: I agree it's for readability - the MS documentation clearly states: If an interpolated string has the type string, it's typically transformed into a String.Format method call. The compiler may replace String.Format with String.Concat if the analyzed behavior would be equivalent to concatenation. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: @John I was going to say the other great use case is the number formatting, but I have just learned that string interpolation can do that too. Didn't know that. This might be the answer to my question.

Comment: It's faster than concatenation and easier to read than string.format. Faster and easier to read are both good arguments for a language feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is in the official reference docs on [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

> String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted strings than a [string composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) feature.

So it's not a whole new language feature to replace string concatenation per se... it's more like syntactic sugar over existing string format functions. In other words, the strengths appear when you're actually formatting the elements in a string:

```
var birthdate = new DateTime(1990,9,22);

Console.WriteLine($"Your birthday is {birthdate:MMMM dd}!");      // string interpolation

Console.WriteLine("Your birthday is {0:MMMM dd}!", birthdate);    // implicit String.Format

var message = "Your birthday is " +
                String.Format("{0:MMMM dd}", birthdate) + "!";    // explicit String.Format

Console.WriteLine(message);

// Your birthday is September 22!
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer because of the links, and specifically calling out the "string composite formatting" feature, which was what I was missing.

Answer (score 5):

> When is string interpolation not equivalent to a simple text
>   replacement of "+ => { and +" => }?

Anything you can do with string interpolation can ultimately be done with concatenation. But interpolation can be quicker to write, easier to read and can (in some instances) perform faster at run time.

An example:

```
var a = 1.23456;
var b = 2.3434;
var check = false;

Console.WriteLine($"Hello {a/2:g7}, it looks like {b%1:g4} {(check ? "really" : "no")}"); // Fast to write, shorter, easier to read
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0:g7}, it looks like {1:g4} {2}", a /2, b % 1, check ? "really" : "no"); // Lack of compile time safety (may be wrong number of parameters)
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + (a/2).ToString("g7") + ", it looks like " + (b%1).ToString("g4") + " " + (check ? "really" : "no")); // Harder to read and write
```

The third code sample was *particularly* hard in terms of getting the spacing right (e.g. the space before `no`). Using string interpolation or `string.Format` (first or second lines) is much easier in that regard.

*Note that the above code actually paints a better picture for the second example (the one with `0:g7`) than is usual, since `Console.WriteLine` has `string.Format` logic built in (i.e. usually the second code line would be even longer).*

String interpolation and its support for `FormattableString` also open up some techniques for generating SQL that is [not open to SQL Injection](https://cmatskas.com/ef-core-string-interpolation-and-sql-injection/) - but that is probably outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of another answer as to why `{thing}` is so much more readable than `"+thing+"`.

Of course there is the basic reason that we programmers are very used to looking at curly braces as a group. However there is a special case where the quotes look a whole lot more awkward than the curly braces.

Compare the following:

```
string s1 = "<div class=\"" + styling + "\">" + content + "</div>";
string s2 = "Field \"" + fieldname + "\" has been submitted with value \"" + fieldvalue + "\".";
string s3 = "select * from [" + dbname + "][" + schemaname + "][" + tablename + "] where " + fieldname + " = '" + escapedvalue + "'";
string s4 = "{\"jsonprop1\":{},\"jsonprop2\": \"" + value + "\"}";
```

to the following:

```
string s1 = $"<div class=\"{styling}\">{content}</div>";
string s2 = $"Field \"{fieldname}\" has been submitted with value \"{fieldvalue}\".";
string s3 = $"select * from [{dbname}][{schemaname}][{tablename}] where " + fieldname + " = '{escapedvalue}'";
string s4 = $"{\"jsonprop1\":{},\"jsonprop2\": \"{value}\"}";
```

It is common that the strings that require having variables inserted into them already contain quotes or single quotes. This makes even more quotes difficult to parse with your eyes.
Thus, simply having another option as an escape character is nice.